# how to understand this vim script?

Tags: editor, vim

The following is vim script from a vim plugin:

vim's syntax is a bit strange:

1. `!exists("*s:SetVals")`, why their is a starmark before `s:`?
2. function!, why there is a `!` character?
3. `&iskeyword`, is this a variable, if yes, where it is defined?
4. what is `s:` and `g:`, what is the difference between them?
5. why let should be used? such as `let &dictionary = g:pydiction_location`, can i change it to be `&dictionary = g:pydiction_location`?

> if !exists("*s:SetVals")
>
> ```
>   function! s:SetVals()
>       " Save and change any config values we need.
>
>       " Temporarily change isk to treat periods and opening 
>       " parenthesis as part of a keyword -- so we can complete
>       " python modules and functions:
>       let s:pydiction_save_isk = &iskeyword
>       setlocal iskeyword +=.,(
>
>       " Save any current dictionaries the user has set:
>       let s:pydiction_save_dictions = &dictionary
>       " Temporarily use only pydiction's dictionary:
>       let &dictionary = g:pydiction_location
>
>       " Save the ins-completion options the user has set:
>       let s:pydiction_save_cot = &completeopt
>       " Have the completion menu show up for one or more matches:
>       let &completeopt = "menu,menuone"
>
>       " Set the popup menu height:
>       let s:pydiction_save_pumheight = &pumheight
>       if !exists('g:pydiction_menu_height')
>           let g:pydiction_menu_height = 15
>       endif
>       let &pumheight = g:pydiction_menu_height
>
>       return ''
>   endfunction
> ```
>
> endif

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary since python is invoked by this script:)

Comment: It could be Ruby or Perl or Lua and it has nothing to do with your question.

Comment: (edited out the `python` tag)

Comment: @romainl you mean vim script can call functions implemented using different programming language?

Comment: @jedwards i want to know how python is invoked by vim script...

Comment: Thats fine, but its still a vim/vimscript question.  Python experts who know nothing about vim will see this appear in their search results only to find a question that they really have no idea about.  As another example, Bash shell scripts invoke Python scripts or compiled c binaries, but we don't generally tag those questions with those tags, because they don't apply -- ie. the Python, C experts wouldn't be able to help.

Comment: Did you try consulting Vim's built-in help before asking this question?

Answer (score 23):

> **1.** `!exists("*s:SetVals")`, why their is a starmark before
>   s:?

The asterisk is special syntax for exists function, and it means that we are checking if there's an existing function called SetVals. The option `iskeyword` could be checked with `exists("&iskeyword")` and the ex command `echo` with `exists(":echo")`

See `:h exists(`

> **2.** `function!`, why there is a ! character?

The exclamation point means that the function is to be replaced if it already exists.

See `:h user-functions`

> **3.** `&iskeyword`, is this a variable, if yes, where it is defined?

That is a vim option. You can check if it's set with `:set iskeyword?`

> **4.** what is `s:` and `g:`, what is the difference between them?

These define the scope of the following symbol. `s:` means that the symbol is local to the script, while `g:` means that the symbol will be global.

See `:h internal-variables` and for `s:` see `:h script-variable`

> **5.** why `let` should be used? such as `let &dictionary =
>   g:pydiction_location, can i change it to be &dictionary =
>   g:pydiction_location`?

Vimscript is one of the languages that require variables to be declared with a keyword. I don't think there's a way to declare variables more easily than with `let`.

Comment: 4.: “define the scope” is true, “symbol can only be used in the current script” is false: there is `s:` — the scope dictionary — and you are free to pass it somewhere else to grant access to script-local variables.

Comment: 5.: there is no requirement for the variables to be declared with a keyword (example: `call extend(g:, {'var': 'val'})` creates g:var variable, no `let` is used), just there is only one type of statements: a command that looks like `[range][command][!][argument[s]][comment]` (all elements are optional, some commands require absence of range, bang, arguments or do not support comments taking them as part of arguments, range without command is “go to last line in range”), there is no “assignment” statement OP is asking for as it does not conform this syntax.

Answer (score 6):

I can answer on a few of those but i'll start with a general comment inspired by your recent questions.

The answers to most of your questions are laid out very clearly in Vim's awesomely exhaustive documentation. If you are serious about using Vim you must know how to use it. Start with `:help` and read carefully. It pays. Trust me.

You can find the answer to all these subquestions in `:help expression`.

- `!exists("*s:SetVals")`, why their is a starmark before `s:`?

  See `:help exists()`.
- `function!`, why there is a `!` character?

  Without an exclamation mark, Vim won't replace the previous definition if you re-source your script.
- `&iskeyword`, is this a variable, if yes, where it is defined?

  That's how you test the value of a vim option in a script. See `:help iskeyword`.
- what is `s:` and `g:`, what is the difference between them?

  These are namespaces. See `:help internal-variables`
- why `let` should be used? such as let `&dictionary = g:pydiction_location`, can I change it to be `&dictionary = g:pydiction_location`?

  No you can't, `:let` is how you define or update a variable. Get used to it.

Answer (score 3):

See `:help eval.txt`. It describes most of vimscript syntax.

Comment: how do you know that this file have most of the specification for vim script, is there any buildin tool with which i can search over all the vim's buildin documents?

Comment: @hugemeow See `:h :helpgrep`, `:helpgrep` is the command for searching through all documentation files.